# php input send to URL, malformed

Tags: php, input, hyperlink, get, malformed

I want to send the text inside the input field to the URL and trigger the $GET function.

```
<form action="" method="get">
URL:<input type="text" name="url" size="100px" placeholder="URL"/>
<select name="url">
    <option value="<?php filter_var($_GET['url'],FILTER_VALIDATE_URL); ?>">testdomain1.de</option>
    <option value="test2">testdomain2</option>
    <option value="test3">testdomain</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Send"/>
</form>
```

It works but link is malformed:

I want this:

```
http://127.0.0.1/title/index.php?url=http://www.tech.de/news/google-will-kein-eigenes-auto-mehr-bauen-10092492.html
```

but I get this

```
http://127.0.0.1/title/index.php?url=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%2Ftitle%2Findex.php%3Furl%3Dhttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.tech.de%2Fnews%2Fgoogle-will-kein-eigenes-auto-mehr-bauen-10092492.html&url=%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0D%0A%3Cb%3ENotice%3C%2Fb%3E%3A++Use+of+undefined+constant+url+-+assumed+%27url%27+in+%3Cb%3EC%3A%5Cxampp%5Chtdocs%5Ctitle%5Cindex.php%3C%2Fb%3E+on+line+%3Cb%3E22%3C%2Fb%3E%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0D%0A
```

could you help me?

ok i read the comments, and changed to this:

```
<?php filter_var($_GET['url'],FILTER_VALIDATE_URL); ?>
```

but it doesn't working, there is no way to paste the plain text to the url?

Comment: You are escaping special characters on the URL, check out http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php for a better way to sanitise urls

Comment: `htmlspecialchars` escapes html chars so you get this results.

Comment: @Aleksandar how is he getting the concatenated value which is his current `url` of the page and the result.

Comment: There is nothing to correct, this is the correct way to send query parameters so that they can be processed on the server. What you want is actually malformed. By the way, you have 2 form fields with the name `url` so that will also lead to unexpected results.

Comment: Action in form leads to self, but it escaped, so it thinks that its relative path, and appends it.

Comment: He can leave action blank to get the correct results, everything else is ok

Comment: according to @AdamHull i try this :  <?php $_GET[filter_var(url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)]?>  - but i cant get it to work

Comment: Also , if you want to use your url in php, you need `$_GET['url']` and not `$_GET[url]`. Note the quotes.

Comment: `<?php filter_var($_GET['url'],FILTER_VALIDATE_URL); ?>`

Comment: Is $_GET['url'] defined already in the URL?

Comment: yes @AdamHull it is

Answer (score 0):

There is the way to get plain text to url, but it's not secure, because you must not use sanitizing like `filter_var` or `htmlspecialchars`.

Also, `$_GET['url']` is not set before submitting the form so first send will lead to errors.

Option here is to include javascript to set `action` in form on `keyup` and then, when you press submit, you will be redirected to this url. If this is not what you want, please, tell us what your script need to do to get the correct answer.